# Move to python3 asyncio from python2 gevent

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm looking over python3 asyncio and it looks pretty awesome, as i'm coming from gevent. However, i'm still trying to figure out how to do everything. Let's say i'm trying to do a simple service that connects to a redis queue and pops items from it. Things get out of hand pretty quickly: i'll need a context manager to close the redis connection when the object gets destroyed, i'll need an async redis driver, and i'll need to catch the SIGINT and SIGTERM signals.

```
import asyncio
import asyncio_redis

class Agent(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("hello, i'm %s" % name)
        self.name = name
        self.running = True

        # self.redis should become an instance of asyncio_redis.Connection

    def shutdown(self):
        self.running = False

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        print("%s cleaned up" % name)
        self.redis.close()

    def loop(self):
        print("%s started looping" % name)
        while self.running:
            # msg should get a value from self.redis.brpop(["queue"], 10)
            if msg:
                print "%s recv %s" % (name, msg)
            else:
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        with a as Agent("agent1"):
            loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, a.shutdown)
            loop.run_until_complete( a.loop() )
    finally:
        loop.stop()
        loop.close()
```

Can anyone complete the code and make it run? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely have a look at [aioredis](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis) and [asyncio-redis](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/asyncio-redis).

I've used both, currently I'm liking aioredis. It has context managers (see the docs for examples) and they are incorporating Python 3.5 syntax.